# Testing Actionmailer on Travis-CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, travis-ci, actionmailer

I've got some code such as this in a Rails model:

```
after_update :email_edits

def email_edits
    EditsMailer.with(record_id: id, user_id: user.id).record_modified.deliver_later
end
```

This is easy enough to unit test locally, e.g.

```
email = EditsMailer.with(record_id: records(:one).id,
                         user_id: users(:one).id).record_modified

assert_emails 1 do
   email.deliver_now
end
```

...but, the inevitable result when this is pushed to Travis-CI and the tests run is:

```
1 emails expected, but 0 were sent.
Expected: 1
Actual: 0
```

Integration tests also fail.

I've seen suggestions of testing whether emails are added to the ActiveJob queue, or overrding `deliver_later` so that `deliver_now` is used in tests, but I am already using `deliver_now` and it still fails.  Even if Travis doesn't allow the sending of emails I'd expect that `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` in `config/environments/test.rb` would still be effective.

Another possible workaround I thought of would be to try disabling those particular tests on Travis, but that would be unsatisfactory. Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found the answer:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

Was only being set in the Travis environment due to variable in a credentials file not being available there.